# Coloring points on a circle

Tags: combinatorics

On a circle there are $n$, $n \ge 3$ points.

In how many ways can we color them in $m$, $m \ge 2$, colors, so that neighbour points have different colors?

We shouldn't use all $m$ colors.

Recurrence relations should be used.

Comment: Have a look to other related questions (e.g. 405109)

Comment: What do you mean by "we shouldn't use all $m$ colors"? Do you mean you want to color the points with only $m-1$ colors?

Comment: Well, there are m ways to color the first point.  m-1 ways to color all but the last and m-2 to do the last one if the second to last one is different than the first and m-1 if the last on is the same as the first.  so $m*[(m-1)^{n-2}(m-2)+(m-1)^{n-3}]$.  If you can't use all colors then you have m choices for the color you can't use and its $m\{(m-1)*[(m-2)^{n-2}(m-3)+(m-2)^{n-3}]\}$.

Comment: @almagest  I took it to mean you should color with m-1 colors but you have m choices as to which color to be left out.  which would be the number of ways to color them with m colors minus the ways that use all m colors.

Comment: Note that this is not that easy even if you are using three colors: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405109/coloring-dots-in-a-circle-with-no-two-consecutive-dots-being-the-same-color?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting aside the sentence, "We shouldn't use all $m$ colors," the number of ways to color $n$ points on a circle with $m$ colors so that neighboring points have different colors is

$$C_n=mN_{n-1}$$

where $N_k$ satisfies the recursion

$$N_{k+1}=(m-2)N_k+(m-1)N_{k-1}\quad\text{with }N_0=0\text { and } N_1=m-1$$

A way to see this is to imagine point $n$ has been colored Red.  If we now color points $1,2,\ldots,k$, and let $R_k$ be the number of colorings that end in Red and $N_k$ be the number that end in Not red, we see easily that

$$R_{k+1}=N_k\quad\text{and}\quad N_{k+1}=(m-2)N_k+(m-1)R_k$$

These combine to give the two-term recursion for $N_k$; the factor $m$ in $C_n=mN_{n-1}$ comes from the fact that point $n$ could be any of $m$ colors, not just Red.

As a sanity check, note that if $m=2$, the recursion is just $N_{k+1}=N_{k-1}$, so the sequence of $N_k$'s alternates between $0$ and $1$, so that

$$C_n=
\begin{cases}
2\text{ if } n\text{ is even}\\
0\text{ if } n\text{ is odd}\\
\end{cases}$$

which is obviously the correct answer with only two colors, since all you can do is try to alternate them around the circle.

I can't think of any good way to incorporate the sentence "We shouldn't use all $m$ colors," except by recasting the above explicitly as functions of $m$ and then using an inclusion-exclusion formula,

$$\sum_{h=1}^{m-2}(-1)^{m-1}{m\choose h}C_n(m-h)$$

(I wonder if the OP meant to say "We *don't have to* use all $m$ colors."  Because then the answer is just the formula for $C_n$ at top.)